# Cannot debug custom Workflow in VS 2010 for SP2010

Tags: 2010

I am having problem to debug sharepoint 2010 custom workflow through VS 2010. When ever I click on start debbuging, I get the following message
[image]

I am dbo.owner on the SharePoint Config Databases. So I do not know why this happening?

Any help much appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like more of a Visual Studio\SP installation issue than a Database issue.. so Im not sure if DB Ownership has much to assist with this.

Can you edit\customize the workflow at all using SharePoint Designer?  Even if thats not the ultimate end solution, perhaps it can help you confirm if the workflow is corrupt at all?